# How to give an OnClick event handler for a row in a list box?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox having a list of items, and what I want is when I click on a specific item, I want to navigate to another page and also send the name of that particular item to the navigated page.

My xaml code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="612" Margin="6,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" Height="50" KeyUp="StackPanel_KeyUp_1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Width="200" Height="44" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbEmail" Width="200" Height="44" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

In the following C# code, I've tried only to navigate to another page, but still it doesn't work,

```
private void StackPanel_KeyUp_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

How can I add keyup event handler for a row? And how should I send the corresponding name of the selected row?

Comment: `KeyUp` is triggered when the user stops pressing a keyboard key. I think you want to use `Tap` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of KeyUp, use Tap events and your code will work just fine.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="612" Margin="6,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" Height="50" Tap="StackPanel_Tap">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Width="200" Height="44" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbEmail" Width="200" Height="44" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Handler: (Here toDoItem is the object type of the ListBox display and AnyUniqueParam is the parameter you want to pass

```
private void StackPanel_Tap(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
    ToDoItem toDoItemToOpen = listBox.SelectedItem as ToDoItem;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewTaskPage.xaml?pagedetails=" + toDoItemToOpen.AnyUniqueParam, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: how to send the name of the selected item as a parameter to the navigated page?

Comment: I have updated the code for sending parameter. You need listBox.SelectedItem as ToDoItem to see which item is clicked and pass any parameter accordingly.